# Spring. Ошибка "No method or field with name 'text' on line 8"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Как это можно решить, появляется ошибка в файле с сокращением mustache:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No method or field with name 'text' on line 8] with root cause

**Код:**

```
@PostMapping("/main")
public String add(@RequestParam String text, Map<String,Object>model){
    Message message=new Message(text);
    messageRepo.save(message);
    Iterable<Message> messages=messageRepo.findAll();   
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "/main";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

    <div>Список сообщений</div>

    <div>
        <span>{{text}}</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это можно решить, если убрать `{{text}}` из шаблона.

Ошибка

> com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No method or field with name 'text' on line 8] with root cause

Это говорит о том, что нет такого поля или метода с названием `text` и поэтому нельзя его использовать в шаблоне при евалюции выражений.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в файле `application.properties` прописать следующее:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. Мне помогло такое решение:

Не запуская приложение, попробуйте просто удалить существующую базу данных, т.к. видимо при её создании произошла какая-то ошибка.
Запусти приложение, оно автоматически создаст новую базу данных, и по идее всё должно заработать.